# Translate GPUImage position with GPUImageTransformFilter and iOS Pan Gesture?

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, transformation, gpuimage

I'm having an issue using the GPUImage transform filter. I'm using the pan gesture recognizer to reposition the image. The code that I have works, but the image moves at about half speed. If I double my `CGAffineTransform newTransform` coordinates, the image drags as expected. However, when I start a new panning gesture, the image jumps to a point about twice the distance from center. Perhaps my math is off. Any ideas? Or, can anyone suggest a better solution than what I have here?

```c
- (void)move:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    // Translated CGPoint from GPUImageView
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.primaryImageView];
    // Current transform from GPUImageTransformFilter
    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.transFilter.affineTransform;
    // Size of GPUImageView bounds for later calculations
    CGSize size = self.primaryImageView.bounds.size;

    if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // Set a beginning CGPoint 
        // Multiply GPUImageView bounds by current transform to get
        // the translated coordinates in pixels.
        self.beginPoint = CGPointMake(size.width*currentTransform.tx, size.height*currentTransform.ty);
    }

    // Calculate difference from beginning point to translated point
    CGPoint updatedPoint = CGPointMake(self.beginPoint.x+translation.x, self.beginPoint.y+translation.y);

    // Create a new transform translation.
    // Divide updated coordinates by GPUImageView bounds to get
    // a percentage value (-1 to 1)
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(updatedPoint.x/(size.width), updatedPoint.y/(size.height));

    // Apply new transform to filter and process.
    [self.transFilter setAffineTransform:newTransform];
    [self.sourcePicture processImage];
}
```

Comment: Instead of trying to yank out the matrix components, what about translating the transform you get back incrementally using `CGAffineTransformTranslate()`? Then you'd just need to scale from the CGPoint translation you get back into a transform for GPUImage.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (and for the great library), @BradLarson. I have come up with a solution using CGAffineTransformTranslate() (in answer). I had to take into account the transform scale as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BradLarson suggested, I have created a solution using `CGAffineTransformTranslate()`. I also discovered that the translate calculation also has to factor in the transform scale to accurately translate the position. Here is my solution:

```
- (void)move:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGPoint translatedPoint = [sender translationInView:self.primaryImageView];
    if ([sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        self.lastPoint = translatedPoint;
    }

    CGSize size = self.primaryImageView.bounds.size;
    // Subtract the last point from the translated point to get the difference.
    CGPoint updatedPoint = CGPointMake(translatedPoint.x-self.lastPoint.x, translatedPoint.y-self.lastPoint.y);
    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.transFilter.affineTransform;
    // Divide updated point by the bounds to get the transform translate value.
    // Multiply transform value by the result of the offset factor divided
    // by the transform scale value.
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(currentTransform, (updatedPoint.x/size.width)*(2/currentTransform.a), (updatedPoint.y/size.height)*(2/currentTransform.a));

    [self.transFilter setAffineTransform:newTransform];
    [self.sourcePicture processImage];
    self.lastPoint = translatedPoint;
}
```

I have set the offset factor to a value of `2`. I'm still not sure why this offset is necessary, but I'm guessing it may have to do with the Retina screen. Although, I have not tested this on a non-retina screen device.